# Scroll issues with review bar when editing short posts

Tags: bug, status-norepro, review, footer, scrolling

When editing a short post in SO's [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/), it doesn't seem to be possible to scroll down to the footer of the page, it just keeps bouncing up. Tested in FF and Chrome.

Curiously, with Chrome, when hitting F12, it lets the page scroll down to the bottom. Same with Firebug on FF. Can anyone reproduce this?

**EDIT:** Fiddling a little bit with the page, it seems it has something to do with the `<div class="review-bar">`.

<strike>Also, this doesn't seem to affect [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/), 
[Late answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers), for instance, is affected.</strike>

It seems to affect only pages with short posts. Specifically, the effect seems to take place when the review bar gets floating, and then page height reduces, and there isn't enough content of the page to be shown. Looks like the review bar gets anchored again. And therefore the bouncing up scroll effect.

**EDIT 2**: Seems this is somehow related with the contents of the page scrolling down (as if the review bar disappeared) when the bar gets floating. This only happens when editing a post.

Comment: Just ran into this myself. It's a worse problem on several non-SO sites (e.g. Game Dev, Arqade, Money) — the fixed/scrolling transition for the review-bar is not seamless even if you're not in edit mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce.

Either due to the new footer or a previous fix, but I can't see this behavior when editing while in the review queue.

Setting to [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro).

Comment: That's right, doesn't seem to happen anymore. Thanks :)